# Isn't the semantic shift from "loosening away" to "relief" identical to that in Latin?

Tags: etymology, latin

John McWhorter [PhD Linguistics (Stanford)](https://americanstudies.columbia.edu/people/john-h-mcwhorter). [*The Power of Babel* (2003)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/006052085X). p. 208 Middle. ([Scan of pp. 208-209](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN0Rs.jpg)).

> *Ablösung* combines the root with the prefix *ab-*. The basic meaning
> of *ab-* is “away”: *abgehen* “to go away.” **But it is hard to see how *Ablösung*, the parts of which appear to signify "loosening away,” comes
> to mean “relief” in the sense of supplementary assistance. [emboldening mine]** This
> meaning arose by a series of gradual reinterpretations, just as silly
> came to mean “ foolish.”

Am I wrong to disagree with the emboldened? How does it differ from [the following](http://membean.com/wrotds/solv-loosen)?

> The Latin roots **solv** and its variant solut both mean “loosen.” Let’s absolutely resolve these roots right now in a resolute fashion!
>
> Let’s begin with the root **solv**, which means “loosen.” A problem or puzzle can be thought of as a knot. When you solve a problem, you “loosen” or untie that knot. When you show resolve in doing so, you are determined to “loosen” that knot no matter what. Once you resolve or set the task to “loosen” the puzzle, you can absolve or “loosen” yourself from this responsibility by using willpower to complete it.

Comment: (1)For the bolded part you should have a look at ***er**lösen*, which clearly binds the *lösen* root to "relief". (2) I absolutely can't see a *semantic shift* here, just a verb stem that has lots of meanings, both figuratively and literally.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want to ask why Latin „absolutio“ is easier to understand than „ablösen“?

Comment: *Ablösung* doesn't mean *relief* in a narrow sense, but *replacement*. Someone or something is set free from service because of a replacement taking over the duty.

Comment: @Janka Ablösung is one of the meanings of relief and I assume that’s what the op wants to say in his very confusing phrase: „“relief” in the sense of supplementary assistance“. But I dare not edit and clarify for fear of having misinterpreted the question.

Comment: LEO lists Ablösung as one of the meanings of relief but also mentions that the actual meaning is "replacement for so. on duty". So "supplementary assistance" is not an appropriate translation of "Ablösung".

Answer (score 1):

I **agree with your disagreement**, provided I understood the question.

*Ablösung* ultimately comes from the PIE root **leṷ(H)-*, probably meaning “divide, loosen, separate” (Pokorny, I, 681). Latin *solu-* is coming from a  compound **se-leṷ-* of the same root with the reflexive particle **s(w)e-* (de Vaan, 573), which, among others, is the source of G. *selbst*.

Your second quotation reads somewhat sloppy (not to disparage the author in the slightest: it comes from a popular blog, not an academic work), but we can find a direct evidence to support this proposition. Latin did indeed develop the semantics of “solve (a problem/riddle)” in post-classical times. A particularly relevant example can be found in Lucretius: *perfacile est parili ratione exsolvere nobis quare fulminius [...] ignis...* (Lucr., Rer., 380), “it's equally easy to resolve with the same reasoning our question how the fire of the lightning *etc.*” Our focus here is the syntax and precise semantics of

perfacile est    |    exsolvere    |    nobis
(it-is-easy)-IMPERS.PRES | (away-from-release)-INF | (us)-PERSPRON.GEN<sub>DISJUNCT</sub>.PL

or, in a literal translation “it is easy to relieve ourselves from [the question how the fire *etc.*],” where *relieve* indeed exposes the semantic development posited:

```
solve < {free/relieve} oneself from [a puzzle]
```

Having said that, I do not see the above as yet a complete explanation of the development of *Ablösung* bringing it close to that of e. g. *Austausch*, although we are just one step away from it. Latin will not probably be helpful here, so let's turn to a closer Germanic language, Old Norse, which had the attested cognate [*lauss* “loose, free, unencumbered; vacant; dissolute.”](https://www.etymonline.com/word/loose) (Harper. *Loose*). The semantic shift of the cognate that you are looking for is quite transparent:

```
augment with an auxiliary < replace with an auxiliary < relieve/free from duty
```

Incidentally, English had a [parallel development in the meaning of the verb *relieve*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/relieve) (Harper. *Relieve*), only with the borrowed lexeme, cognate with *levitation* and coming via French from the L. root found in *levis*, “light,” not related to PIE **leṷ-*. This is also quite expected, as it was the French-fancying nobility who sent the relief to their peers in a battle, not the English-speaking peasantry.